# Restoring a WRKLNK file

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm hoping someone could help me if there's a possible way to find or restore a WRKLNK file. I have admin access but I don't know the commands that can possibly restore the file I need.
I tried to check RSTOBJ, but it's parameter don't have place where I can put the path and file I want to restore.
This is the path:

```
/p400/MYDEV/Test/
```

This is the file:

```
Testfile_20240321.txt
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the plain `rst` command.